# KDE konsole command line option --profile not working

Tags: kde, profile, konsole

I'm running KDE 4.11 on CentOS 7.5.1804 (Core), with konsole package 'konsole-4.10.5-4.el7.x86_64'.

Within the konsole application I created a profile named 'pi@eecspi', and from within a running konsole window I can create a new konsole tab that's based on that profile:

```
konsole window > File menu > New Tab > pi@eecspi
```

However, when I invoke any of these command lines

```
konsole --profile pi@eecspi
konsole --profile 'pi@eecspi'
konsole --profile "pi@eecspi"
konsole --profile=pi@eecspi
konsole --profile='pi@eecspi'
konsole --profile="pi@eecspi"
```

from a command prompt (e.g., Bash shell or ALT+F2), the resulting konsole window opens with the default profile and not the pi@eecspi profile.

If I change the profile name from 'pi@eecspi' to 'eecspi', then the command lines shown above all work as intended (after changing 'pi@eecspi' to 'eecspi', of course):

```
konsole --profile eecspi
```

This opens a konsole window with the profile 'eecspi'.

For what it's worth, I'm 99% sure I've used konsole profile names similar to 'pi@eecspi' on other KDE systems and had no problem invoking a konsole with that profile from a command line.

I've done some troubleshooting, but haven't been able to figure out why this is happening. Any ideas what I might try to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I never did figure out what was causing this.  I managed to solve this only by the brute force approach of creating a new $HOME directory for the affected user, and then logging as as that user and manually reconfiguring the environment:

- Logged off the affected user account (e.g., username)
- Logged on as root
- Renamed the affected user's $HOME directory (e.g., /home/username -> /home/username.old)
- Created a new $HOME directory for the affected user

x

```
[root]# cd /home
[root]# cp -a /etc/skel /home/username
[root]# chown -R username /home/username
[root]# chgrp -R username /home/username
```

- Logged off as root
- Logged back on to the affected user account (username)
- Manually recovered and reconfigured everything in username's environment

Comment: It would be nice if the KDE folks would read this. There are simple things I want to do, such as running a ruby script in one tab of kde konsole on startup, but the syntax is so abysmal; and the examples I found did not work. People in KDE need to learn that simplicity is a good thing.